# SignalR and single user authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, signalr

I created a sort of chat application in a asp.net MVC5. I have chosen single user authentication when creating the project. So now people can register and login.

After that i created a SignalR hub. Now i have to map the users from the single user authentication to the correct client in the hub.

I also want to get the username or any claims of it.

How can i do this? There are many questions and answers about this, but i never see something about single user authentication.

I've tried to use the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Authorize` and the `System.Web.Mvc.Authorize` (that one use the controllers to) attribute above the hub. But they gave both a 401 unauthorized.